# How to get difference of months replicating Excel behavior

Tags: timedelta, python-polars

I would like to **subtract** `two date columns` and get their **difference** in **months** `unit` instead of days but haven't been able to.

Data:

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

test_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "dt_end": [datetime(2022, 1, 1).date(), datetime(2022, 1, 2).date()],
        "dt_start": [datetime(2021, 5, 7).date(), datetime(2020, 7, 8).date()],
    }
)
```

This gives difference in Days

```
test_df.with_columns(
    diff_months = pl.col('dt_end') - pl.col('dt_start')
)
```

output:

```
dt_end  dt_start    diff_months
date    date    duration[ms]
2022-01-01  2021-05-07  239d
2022-01-02  2020-07-08  543d
```

I have tried below code for **months** but that **doesn't work**

```
test_df.with_columns(
    diff_months = pl.duration(months = pl.col('dt_end') - pl.col('dt_start'))
)
```

**UPDATE**

Have also tried below code but that also gives me a different value from the excel.

```
test_df.with_columns(
    diff_months = (pl.col('dt_end').dt.year() - pl.col('dt_start').dt.year()) * 12 +
                    (pl.col('dt_end').dt.month().cast(pl.Int32) - pl.col('dt_start').dt.month().cast(pl.Int32)) 
)
```

output:

```
dt_end  dt_start    diff_months
date    date    i32
2022-01-01  2021-05-07  8
2022-01-02  2020-07-08  18
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I think this is the **manual** way of doing it by using **30.42** as the **avg** number of days in month

```
test_df.with_columns(
    diff_months = pl.col('dt_end') - pl.col('dt_start')
).with_columns(
    diff_months = (pl.col('diff_months').dt.days()/30.42).floor().cast(pl.Int8)
)
```

output

```
dt_end  dt_start    diff_months
date    date    i8
2022-01-01  2021-05-07  7
2022-01-02  2020-07-08  17
```

**UPDATE 3:** Snapshot of actual data with desired Reference excel value

```
# Data
snapshot_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Reporting Month": [datetime(2000, 7, 20).date(), datetime(2000, 8, 20).date(), datetime(2000, 9, 20).date()],
        "Origination date": [datetime(1999, 12, 19).date(), datetime(1999, 12, 19).date(), datetime(1999, 12, 19).date()],
        "Excel_Reference_Age": [7,8,9]
    }
)
```

comparison

```
snapshot_df.with_columns(
    diff_months = pl.col('Reporting Month') - pl.col('Origination date')
).with_columns(
    diff_months = (pl.col('diff_months').dt.days()/30.42).floor().cast(pl.Int16),

    diff_months_1 = (pl.col('Reporting Month').dt.year() - pl.col('Origination date').dt.year()) * 12 +
                    (pl.col('Reporting Month').dt.month().cast(pl.Int32) - pl.col('Origination date').dt.month().cast(pl.Int32)) ,

    diff_months_2 = pl.date_range(pl.col("Origination date"), pl.col("Reporting Month"), "1mo").list.lengths()
).select('Excel_Reference_Age','diff_months','diff_months_1','diff_months_2')
```

output

```
Excel_Reference_Age diff_months diff_months_1   diff_months_2
i64 i16 i32 u32
7   7   7   8
8   8   8   9
9   9   9   10
```

Comment: Can you try this `test_df.with_columns(diff_months=pl.date_range(pl.col("dt_start"), pl.col("dt_end"), "1mo").list.lengths())`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM this seems to work but getting a different value from what I get in `excel`. In excel `difference` I get is `7,17` but in `polars` using ur code I am getting `8,18`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I also tried your approach on dataset of `Row count: 761403` and it came out to be 10-15 times slower so imho following would be a better option: `test_df.with_columns(
    diff_months = pl.col('dt_end') - pl.col('dt_start')
).with_columns(
    diff_months = (pl.col('diff_months').dt.days()/30.42).floor().cast(pl.Int16)
)`

Comment: Here's a series of semi rhetorical question, how many months are between 2/1/2023 and 3/1/2023? what about 2/1/2024 and 3/1/2024? and 7/1/2023 and 8/1/2023? Are they all one? By your update 2, they're 0.92, 0.95, and 1.02 but you're also taking the floor so then it's 0,0,1. Are you trying to get the number of times the month changed so for instance 12/31/2022 to 1/2/2023 is 1 as would be 12/15/2022 to 1/20/2023?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I have fanniemae Monthly **Loan Data** which has `Loan Origination` & `Reporting Month` date as - (19-12-1999, 20-07-2000) respectively and I need to use `Loan Age`. **Excel** `DATEDIF()` Formula gives me `7` as the difference which is the `Loan Age` and I am trying to stay in **sync** with excel as I don't want to cause two different  calculations when using two different tools. Another example is  - (19-12-1999, 20-08-2000) and so on and I am getting `8` for this. I will update the code & snapshot in `UPDATE 3` for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update #1 is just fine, you just also need to adjust by 1 if `dt.days` for `end` has not reached `start`:

```py
test_df.with_columns(
    diff_months=12 * (pl.col('dt_end').dt.year() - pl.col('dt_start').dt.year())
    + (
        pl.col('dt_end').dt.month().cast(pl.Int32)
        - pl.col('dt_start').dt.month().cast(pl.Int32)
    )
    - (pl.col('dt_end').dt.day() < pl.col('dt_start').dt.day()).cast(pl.Int32)
)
```